# Is there a way to call a constant function asynchronously?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, metamask

I'm trying to invoke a constant function **test** from a webpage. I've injected **web3** object through **MetaMask**.

```
contract A {
     function test(uint8 x) constant returns(uint8) {
        return x + 10;
    }
}
```

My JS code:

```
var contractA = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition).at(address);
var retVal = contractA.test(10);
```

I get an error:

```
The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods
```

Is there an async version of this api method?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make an asynchronous request, you can pass an optional callback as the last parameter to most functions. All callbacks are using an error first callback style:

```
 var contractA = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition).at(address);
 contractA.test(10, function(error, result){
     if(!error)
         console.log(result)
     else
         console.error(error);
 });
```